# Blazor - How to bind list of classes to input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In the `//this works`, the `item.isSelected` is updated but the `set` in `private List<CheckboxModel> checkboxes` won't run. And in the `//this causes infinite loop in this component`, nothing is updated and the `foreach` loop keeps running infinitely.

```
        @foreach (var item in checkboxes)
        {
            //this works 
            @*<div class="checkbox" @key="item">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@item.text" @bind="item.isSelected">
                <label for="@item.text">@item.text</label>
            </div>*@
            Console.WriteLine(item.text);
            //this causes infinite loop in this component
            <Checkbox id="@item.text" @key="item" label="@item.text" @bind-isSelected="item.isSelected" />
        }
```

```
    private List<CheckboxModel> _checkboxes { get; set; } = new List<CheckboxModel>();

    private List<CheckboxModel> checkboxes
    {
        get => _checkboxes;
        set
        {
            
            // won't run
            _checkboxes = value;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', value.Where(x => x.isSelected).Select(x => x.text)));
        }
    }
```

This is `CheckboxModel.cs`

```
    public class CheckboxModel
    {
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

`Checkbox.razor`

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="@id" @bind="@isSelected">
    <label for="@id">@label</label>
</div>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string label { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool isSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            isSelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> isSelectedChanged { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Was not storing the passed-in value into _isSelected intentional, by the way?

Comment: *set in private List<CheckboxModel> checkboxes won't run* - I can't see any code that calls it.. if it's never called how can the infinite loop even start?

Comment: @CaiusJard ya I will edit it but I tried storing it but it doesn't change anything cause it wasn't called (ntg is logged into the console)

Comment: @CaiusJard i wasn't sure why the infinite loop even started but all I get from console when I select the checkbox was infinite logging of  `Console.WriteLine(item.text);`

Comment: Put a check in before you invoke IsSelectedChanged to verify that the value really is different to _isSelected

Comment: It's the same, the infinite loop still happens. I wonder if it has anything to do with this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24916)

Comment: Set the for loop aside for a moment, and just out a single Checkbox on a page and bind it to a single CheckboxModel..

Comment: Ya it works in single but if I remove the check to verify if the value is different to _isSelected it will go into an infinity loop and if I add a loop for it the data won't bind. i am guessing its because I am passing a value from `List` and changing the value won't trigger a rerender, cause I should set the `List` and not the value in the `List`. But I found a workaround [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21532) and it works. Thanks for helping out tho. Much appreciated.

Comment: You should post up your solution as an answer so it can be of future benefit to others

Comment: Sure I will post it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

What I end up doing was changing `Checkbox.razor`  to
`CheckboxList.razor`

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <div class="checkbox" @key="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="@item.text" checked="@item.isSelected" @onchange="args=> checkedChanged(item,args)">
        <label for="@item.text">@item.text</label>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<CheckboxModel> items { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<CheckboxModel>> itemsChanged { get; set; }

    async Task checkedChanged(CheckboxModel item, ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        item.isSelected = (bool)args.Value;
        await itemsChanged.InvokeAsync(items);
    }
}
```

and in the parent file

```
<CheckboxList @bind-items="checkboxes" />
@code {
    private List<CheckboxModel> checkboxes { get; set; }
}
```

You can find 2 links in [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21532).
One of them is [simpler](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/7c5e80ebf7f238505f1281f550666600) and the other one [has a select all button](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/3b27b3d2ad99997e49cae4d74a225223)

In short: I let the child component handle the logic of looping and handling the List passed into it. The child component passes the List back instead of just a bool which fixes the problem where it doesn't trigger the setter function when I update an item in a List.